# How to use NetBeans in Dark Mode with the Darcula Theme?

Tags: java, programming, development, netbeans, ide

How do I install [Darcula](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1040/how-to-use-netbeans-in-dark-mode-with-the-darcula-theme) through Netbeans itself?

[image: plugins]

Seemingly a matter of enabling the correct plugins through the GUI?

Versus installing after manually downloading:

[image: manual]

I'd expect it to be [available](https://github.com/Revivius/nb-darcula) through the GUI as:

> The most recent stable version of this plugin is available at the
>   NetBeans Plugin Portal as Darcula LAF for NetBeans and thus it can be
>   installed from "Tools|Plugins|Available Plugins" from the NetBeans
>   IDE.

or some alternate dark type theme...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darcula LaF is only downloadable from the pre-Apache NetBeans catalog (http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/) and not the Apache one (https://netbeans.apache.org/plugins/index.html).

To install it on Apache NetBeans, you will need to add this catalog as a plugin source.

To do this :

- open NetBeans ;
- go to Tools > Plugins ;
- the Plugins window opens. Click on the "Settings" tab ;
- click "Add" to add a new update center ;
- name it as you wish and provide the following URL: http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/8.2/catalog.xml.gz then click "Ok". I think it's here that you did not provide the correct URL :) The number of available plugins should suddenly raise ;
- You should now be able to find Darcula LaF !

Alternatively, and as you seems to know already, you can download the Darcula archive from plugins.netbeans.org and  install it manually from the Tools > Plugins > Downloaded tab.

Enjoy and save your eyes ;)

Comment: URL is dead, 8.2 plugins are available now.